# How do you increase the search levels for the PokeNav?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

So far in Alpha Sapphire I have seen levels of about anywhere from 1-12 for random Pokémon that are hiding, but I do not how to increase the level (or even if the level really matters).

How do you increase the search levels for the PokeNav?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You increase the search level by **encountering Pokemon.**
In your Pokedex you will have a line that says "Encountered: x times" for  each Pokemon, and your search level for that particular Pokemon is going to be the same as the times encountered.